# Edebug Backtrace keeps disappearing

Tags: debugging, edebug, backtrace

Has anyone found any way to step through the code using edebug and see how variables change on each step in the backtrace? On my emacs each time you run `edebug-next-mode` backtrace disappears and you have to invoke it again, which quickly turns into a difficult workflow.

Comment: Have you tried using the ordinary Emacs Lisp debugger instead of edebug? Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to find out why one variable changes from its initial state and it's really hard without a way to track it. If you knew a good resource which explains how to set a breakpoint, step and track the variables that would be really helpful. I found edebug much easier to start with and couldn't find anything for the regular debugger.

Comment: Maybe try function `add-variable-watcher`? (Never tried, myself.)

Comment: Thank you very much, although I couldn't find `add-variable-watcher` function in my emacs,  it led me to another function called `debug-on-variable-change` and what looks like a fantastic resource on doom emacs in general: https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Variable-Debugging

Comment: Yes, `add-variable-watcher` and related functions were added in Emacs 28, I think.

Answer (score 0):

As a poor man's workaround I've rebound `d` to open backtrace and go back to the main window (so by pressing quickly `n` for `next-mode` and `d` for this funciton with a bit of flickering you can somewhat step through AND have a traceback):

```el
(defun edebug-pop-to-backtrace-and-return ()
        (interactive)
        (edebug-pop-to-backtrace)
        (windmove-up))

(map! :map edebug-mode-map "d" 'edebug-pop-to-backtrace-and-return)
```

This is by not means a solution. If anyone found a better way to do it please let me know.

UPDATE: This won't work if you also want to watch local variables. Still looking for a "proper" solution...